# How to Mock __init__ and resolvers with various arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I've seen a lot of examples of mock tests but none that show how one could mock something like `<graphql.execution.base.ResolveInfo object at 0x106f002a8>`

For instance, if I wanted to test that the two methods in this class were working properly, how would I mock the values that are being passed in?

```
class mySearch(graphene.ObjectType):
    my_search = graphene.Field(
       MySearchWrapper,
       query = graphene.String(description="Search query")
    )

    def __init__(self, args, context, info):
        super(mySearch, self).__init__()


    def resolve_my_search(self, args, context, info):
        return promisify(MySearchWrapper, args, context, info)
```

The `__init__` method returns:

`args: {}, context: <Request 'http://localhost:8080/graphql' [POST]>, info: <graphql.execution.base.ResolveInfo object at 0x106f000c8>`

And the `resolve_my_search` method returns:

`args: {'page_type': [u'MyCorgi', u'YourCorgi'], 'query': u'Corgi family', 'domain': u'corgidata.com'}, context: <Request 'http://localhost:8080/graphql' [POST]>, info: <graphql.execution.base.ResolveInfo object at 0x106f002a8>`

I know I can mock the dictionary value with `mock_args.json.return_value` but... not sure about the Request and object. Any ideas? Guidance? I've already spent a week on this and have found no way out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) python package. Here is an example:

```
from unittest import mock

info = mock.create_autospec(graphql.execution.base.ResolveInfo)
info.context.user = AnonymousUser()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.  You can tweak it to mock the `GraphQLResolveInfo` but for this use case I only needed to mock the `Request` object.

```
from requests import Requests
from unittest.mock import patch

from starlette.authentication import AuthenticationError

@patch("grapql.type.definition.GraphQLResolveInfo.context")
def test_func(context_mock):
    with pytest.raises(AuthenticationError):
        context_mock.side_effect = Request()
        func_to_be_tested(resolver("fake_source", info_mock, data_inputs))
```